# Mobile "GIS"/geolocalization application for popularisation of science?

Tags: qgis, geolocation, mobile, mobile-gis

I am looking for an mobile multi-platform (or at least Android) application which will allow me to share my spatial data.

On day to day bases I am working with QGIS in archaeology and with Losuc GIS in the field. I have developed some interpretaions (remote sensing based) which I would like to share withe the public. I am looking for an application which would allow me to put a single link (QR code) on the information board that is placed on the archaeological site and which would refer to a mobile platform which would use geolocalization and which would contain my data (vector and if possible some raster). It has to be easy, simple and user-friendly. I would not like to share the data separately as I think it would be to complicated and not user-friendly enough. I am looking for an solution which would not require IT skills from me.

I've tryed using Google Earth online (earth.google.com) but it seems like the date is not apearing on mobiel devices (I guess its still in development phase).

Does such a system exists or should rather seek help within IT framework to develop specially for my purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IF your aim is to only display some information and doesn't want the public to interact with it you could use [QGISCloud](https://api.qgiscloud.com/). It allows you to create Web maps and you can upload your data to their server to be displayed in a web map.

There are free accounts but because we are using the paid service your approach might be a little bit different. 
The workflow would be:

- Create an account on their website (see link above)
- Download the plugin for QGIS
- Create your QGIS project with all the data you want to show and upload it via the plugin
- Make the map public available: under "Maps" click on the "edit" button under "Actions" and check the option "Map viewer accessible without login"
- now you can create a QR Code from the Map URL

**Disclaimer:** I am not affiliated with QGIS Cloud.

Comment: Yest It is a possible option, just that the mobile client is only in Pro option which in the longer run would be a bit expensieve - I think it is a good option If You have more projects to publish :)

Comment: @archeogis So if you have a free account the website won't scale respond its design?  hm my bad :/ and jeah I agree, that's a little bit expensive for small-scale projects

Comment: I will have to experiment with it, its just not prepared for mobile devices and by that its not that stable in the free option. In short You can view it through a browser on a mobile device, but I would prefere a little better quality of use. Its a start and better than nothing - thanks for the direction :)